# Fetching association with selected options in dropdown PHP CART

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

When i select a product in my gallery it goes to my cart.
I get my product id and store them in a session.
And in my cart i got to select size and which fabric i want to order my product.
My product is cushion.
My cart.php has all function to make the cart session work,
and has all the buttons functions too.
I display my selected products in my page checkout.php ... i call my cart function in that page...

To select size and fabric i have 2 dropdowns, the size dropdown is static html options, and my fabrics are getting data from my DB.

Look this image before...
[image: i'm trying to...]
As you see i got these two tables.
When i select my fabric and it size i want to fetch the value in the fabrics prices table.
My cart a got a session where it grabs the user state.
If the user is in the same state that i am,the price of the fabric will be one cost else it will be other cost.(IN_state,Out_state columns).
My QNTD row in the cart table is quantity `$value`

Valor is value of costs in pt-br.

A bad thing is that my dropdown dont save the selected option.
lets say that i selected a fabric *Velvet* and size 50x50.
And i click on add or less button my page will refresh and all options will be lost.

What i did is store the selected option using LocalStorage.
It works only for the first row in the checkout.

How can i get all these data to work with out submitting something.
Maybe i can use more sessions to get all data and make the calculation.
But im a bit lost in all this.
What can i do to get this working all together ?
my cart code..

```
 <?php 
 include_once '../incluedes/conn_cms.php'; 

// gets the product id from gallery and store in session and add +1


if(isset($_GET['add'])){
    $select = "SELECT * FROM gallery2 WHERE id=" . escape_string($_GET['add'])." ";
    $run_selection = mysqli_query($conn,$select);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_selection)){
    if($rows['id'] != $_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['add']]){
        $_SESSION['product_' . $_GET['add']]+=1;
        header('Location: index.php');
            }else{
                $msg = "error";
                header('Location: checkout.php');
                }
             }
}

//the plus button

if(isset($_GET['plus'])){
$_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['plus']]+=1;
if($_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['plus']] < 1){
        header('Location: checkout.php');

}else{

    header('Location: checkout.php');
    }}

 //the minus button
if(isset($_GET['remove'])){
$_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['remove']]--;
if($_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['remove']] < 1){
        header('Location: checkout.php');

}else{

    header('Location: checkout.php');
    }

}

  //the remove button

if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['delete']] = '0';
    header('Location: checkout.php');
}

function cart(){
    global $conn;


    $fabric_options = '';
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM almofadas";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

       $fabric_options .= "<option value=''>{$rows['tecido']}</option>";
      }

     foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if($value > 0){
            if(substr($name, 0, 8 ) == "product_"){
                $length = strlen($name) -8;
                $item_id = substr($name,8 , $length);

                $query = "SELECT * 
                          FROM gallery2 
                          WHERE gallery2.id =".escape_string($item_id). "";
                $run_item = mysqli_query($conn,$query);



                while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_item)){ 
                    $vari = $rows['variante'];
                    $num = $rows['title'];
                    $id = $rows['id'];

                    $btn_add='<a class="btn btn-success" href="cart.php?plus='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" add_btn></i></a>';
                    $btn_remove = '<a class="btn btn-warning" href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" remove_btn></i></a>';
                    $btn_delete='<a class="btn btn-default delete_btn" href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
                    if($rows['variante'] < 1){
                        $vari="";
                    }else{
                        $vari = "-".$rows['variante'];
                    }
                    $product = '
                        <td style="width:100px; "><img src="../'.$rows['image'].'" style="width:90%;border: 1px solid black;"></td>
                        <td>'.$num.''.$vari.'</td>
                        <td style="width:15%;">
                            <select id="fabric" class="form-control selectpicker" required="" >

                            '. $fabric_options . '  

                            </select>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <select  id="size" class="form-control selectpicker" required style="width:80%;"  >
                                <option value="50">50x50</option>
                                <option value="45">45x45</option>

                            </select>

                         </td>
                            <td>'.$value.'</td>
                        <td>R$</td>
                        <td>sub.total</td>
                        <td> 
                         '.$btn_add.' '.$btn_remove.' '.$btn_delete.'
                        </td>
                        </tr>';
                    echo $product;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My LocalStorage script in checkout.php

```
<script >
  $(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('fabric')) {
        $("#fabric option").eq(localStorage.getItem('fabric')).prop('selected', true);
    }

    $("#fabric").on('change', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('fabric', $('option:selected', this).index());
    });
});

</script>

<script >
  $(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('size')) {
        $("#size option").eq(localStorage.getItem('size')).prop('selected', true);
    }

    $("#size").on('change', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('size', $('option:selected', this).index());
    });
});

</script>
```